# Loop within main loop in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, pygame

I'm fairly new to python and pygame.  I'm trying to make a simple game as a practice.  My problem is how do I have a loop (or many loops) inside the main game loop so that the graphic also updates inside sub loops?  For example I have a button and a rectangle, if I press on the button I want the rectangle to move across the screen.  Things I've tried:

- Another while loop, it works but the rectangle won't "move" and just appears wherever the loop is finished
- Custom event, however it either works once per frame or continuously in case of set_timer() function

Here's my code:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
running = True
window = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
window.fill((255, 255, 255))
btn = pg.Rect(0, 0, 100, 30)
rect1 = pg.Rect(0, 30, 100, 100)

while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (mouseX, mouseY) = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            if(btn.collidepoint((mouseX, mouseY))):
                rect1.x = rect1.x + 1
        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
    #end event handling

    pg.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 255), rect1, 1)
    pg.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 255), btn)

    pg.display.flip()

#end main loop
pg.quit()
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement some kind of state. Usually, you would use the `Sprite` class, but in your case, a simple variable would do.

---

Take a look at this example:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
running = True
window = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
window.fill((255, 255, 255))
btn = pg.Rect(0, 0, 100, 30)
rect1 = pg.Rect(0, 30, 100, 100)

move_it = False
move_direction = 1

while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (mouseX, mouseY) = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            if(btn.collidepoint((mouseX, mouseY))):
                move_it = not move_it

        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
    #end event handling

    if move_it:
        rect1.move_ip(move_direction * 5, 0)
        if not window.get_rect().contains(rect1):
            move_direction = move_direction * -1
            rect1.move_ip(move_direction * 5, 0)

    pg.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 255), rect1, 1)
    pg.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0) if move_it else (0, 255, 255), btn)

    pg.display.flip()

#end main loop
pg.quit()
```

When the button is pressed, we just set the `move_it` flag.
Then, in the main loop, we check if this flag is set, and then move the `Rect`.

---

[image]

---

You should avoid creating multiple logic loops (sorry, I don't have a better word) in your game; see the problems you mentioned. Aim for one single main loop that does three things: input handling, game logic, and drawing.